# Opencv and Gstreamer

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

i'm trying to send opencv video **cv2.VideoCapture()** 
bash code work excelent, but when I copy it to appsrc it don't want to work

bash:

```
send `gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device='/dev/video0' ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1,encoding-name=JPEG! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000`

recv `gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)JPEG" ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! videorate ! autovideosink sync=false
```

python code:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

four = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter()
out.open("appsrc ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1,encoding-name=JPEG! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000",four,30.0,(640,480))

if(out.isOpened()):
    print('d')
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        out.write(frame)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change occurs because of the data format. Your camera seems to capture images in JPEG format. However OpenCv matrices are raw BGR images, and `VideoCapture` element converts the jpeg images from camera to raw BGR OpenCv matrices.

There are two changes needed:

- You need to pass `0` as your `fourcc`.
- Your caps `video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1,encoding-name=JPEG` will fail to link since your `appsrc` is raw BGR image. You need to remove `encoding-name` parameter from the caps. New caps will be: `video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1`.

Comment: unfourtenately it isn't issue for my problem, I tested it, but no result, there is no exception, no errors, nothing, and there is no errors from basg gstreamer receiver

Comment: for me issue was this gstreamer pipeline: `appsrc ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=BGR,framerate=20/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=I420 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000`